How to control the access permission to the specific folder for Jenkins when the job is triggered by different user
I've created admin, userA, userB, and userC within the Jenkins Web UI.
 (link)
With the Role-based Authorization Strategy plugin, I can assign different permissions to different users to control access/buildjobs for various projects.
However, in the file system where jobs build the .robot file or other scripts, there's a disconnect with the user triggering the job. The job always runs under the "jenkins" username, granting it access to all files and folders.
For example:

userA triggers the job to build the script for /jenkins/userA/job1 (Build Steps > Execute Shell).
The Jenkins server uses the "jenkins" username to access files under /jenkins/userA/job1.
Even though I restrict the folder/file permission to each user, I still have to add the permission with "jenkins" username to all of the folder/file to let the Jenkins server been able to run the jobs. This allows userB to access userA's files through the permission of "jenkins".

After some research, I discovered that the JENKINS_USER variable might be able to changed by using the build user vars plugin to set JENKINS_USER to BUILD_USER.
Is there any way or default variable that can be set to JENKINS_USER and JENKINS_GROUP to match the username triggering the job?
For instance:

userA triggers the job.
JENKINS_USER could be set to userA.
With JENKINS_USER set to userA, it would allow access only to files owned by userA. This way, userB cannot access userA's files using the JENKINS_USER.

Role-based Authorization Strategy
build user vars
Thanks,
Tim
